# Can I use Titanium to draw realtime graphics and use ORM db?

Tags: core-data, opengl-es, orm, cross-platform, titanium

My background: I have experience with iOS programming, and very little Java. I have been looking on the web, looking at code examples and searching for fx core-data on the titanium website which doesn't helped me alot.

Problem: My new project includes functionalities for:

1. Camera (bar code reading and analyzing)
2. A lot of image processing with custom graphic animation displayed fx. a wheel that should rotate by finger touches.
3. ORM db similiar like Core-Data or which one? Plain sqlite?

Question: Does Titanium crossplatform support these 3 steps? (targeting iphone and android platform).

**Just some clear answers please - not discussion !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depends on the device, should work for Android and iOS but i didn't checked
2. Titanium is interpreted JavaScript so not much for advanced or heavy stuff
3. sqllite should be available on most devices

I think your step 2 is the deal-breaker here.